# Numerical solution of Schrodinger equation

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following differential equations:
[image]

Subject to the conditions:

[image]

I have written the following code for the first equation:

```
 NDSolve[{-D[imu[t, z], t] == -1/2 D[reu[t, z], z, z] - 3 z reu[t, z], D[reu[t, z], t] == -1/2 D[imu[t, z], z, z] - 3 z imu[t, z], 
reu[0, z] == Exp[-z^2]/{\pi}^{1/4}, imu[0, z] == 0}, 
reu[t, z], {t, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

Where imu[t,z] indicates the imaginary part and reu[t,z] indicates the real part of the equation.

I cannot figure out the error.

Comment: Your code is very confusing. You show the dependent variables being `imu` and `reu` but then in the call you change to `u[t,z]`.  You also say all of this is only for the first ode? I thought you had two coupled odes? Do you have typo when you said for `first` ode? You can't just write `imu` and `reu` and assumes Mathematica will know these are for imaginary and real parts of `u`

Comment: @Nasser Is it fine now. First equation only means first one. I don't know if the second one has to inserted in the list or not.

Comment: $reu[t,z]$ and $imu[t,z]$ refer to the real and imaginary parts of the first equation(the one for $\Psi_{+}$).

Comment: @Nasser I have separated the real and imaginary parts myself. $imu[t,z]$ and $reu[t,z]$ does not mean that mathematica has to separate them. Used those labels for my own understanding.

Comment: Lets step back a little, ok? Do you have one ode or two?  (without any separation stuff). In your latex, you show 2 separate ode's, right?  the plus one and the minus one. SO you want to solve for $\Psi_{+}$ and $\Psi_{-}$ ?  Also, you need boundary conditions since you are using numerical solution. You only gave initial conditions.  Once we sort these details then we will go to writing code.

Comment: @Nasser Forget about the second equation for the time. Secondly, this is in one dimension case so all I would need is the waveform at $t=0$. Isn't that sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

> Forget about the second equation for the time.

In this case, just solve it as is. There is no need to split in real and imaginary parts. Mathematica is smart enough to handle it as is.

> this is in one dimension case so all I would need is the waveform at
> t=0

Well, this is numerical solver. Not analytic. So you need to give it BC. Here, I made some up. Feel free to change these.

```
ode = I*D[w[z,t],t] ==-1/2* D[w[z,t],{z,2}]-3*z*w[z,t]
ic = w[ z,0] == Exp[-z^2]/(Pi/2)^(1/4)
bc = {w[0, t] == 0,w[1,t]==1}
sol=NDSolve[{ode, ic,bc}, w, {t, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The solution at t=.3 seconds is

```
 ReImPlot[Evaluate[w[z, .3] /. sol], {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At 1 second

```
ReImPlot[Evaluate[w[z,1]/.sol],{z,0,1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Naseer Is there a way to plot the graph at a particular time without using the ReImPlot. Actually, I am using Mathematica 11.2 in which this function is not available.

Comment: @MShehzad:  Use `Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[w[z, .3] /. sol]], {z, 0, 1}]` instead.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert It works. Thanks.